# Is it a bug or am I wrong? Syntax error on int processing

Tags: syntax, processing

I'm kinda new to processing and I've been trying to set two variables, but while I'm setting the rest of the code, I get an error

> Syntax error: error on "int"

I've tried to change the name of the variables and such but it keeps happening.

Here's the code:

```
int circulox = 100
int circuloy = 100

void setup() {
    background(255);
    size(500,500);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed the semicolons (`;`). The [Processing](https://processing.org/) syntax is based on Java. In Java (unlike in JavaScript/TypeScript) a statement must be terminated with a semicolon:

```java
int circulox=100;
int circuloy=100;

void setup(){
    background(255);
    size(500,500);
}
```